# AddType (css, js) not working after Apache 2.3.x

Tags: apache

After moving an old server to Apache 2.4 all of our

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

.. 'esque directives have stopped working.

mod_mime and all of the same configurations are in place.

Answer (score 2):

After Apache 2.3.x the `DefaultType` directive has been removed and replaced with the `ForceType` directive.

Note that the `ForceType` directive *overrides* any `AddType` directives.

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype